# How to send character utf8 to sever by library net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1 in nadroid

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want pass image and multi string to server..
for send image to server ,I use library "net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1"

but,because my character is utf8,when save in db ,displayed ????
What should I do?

my code in android:

```
new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, Constants.UPLOAD_URL)
        .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
        .addParameter("name", strFileName)
        .addParameter("iduser", iduser+"") //Adding text parameter to the request
        .addParameter("madah",madah.getText().toString() )
        .addParameter("phone",phone.getText().toString())
        .addParameter("sokhanran",sokhanran.getText().toString())
        .addParameter("startdate", startdate.getText().toString())
        .addParameter("enddate",enddate.getText().toString())
        .addParameter("descript", descriptin.getText().toString())
        .addParameter("linkax", linkax)
        .addParameter("address",address.getText().toString())
        .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
        .setMaxRetries(2)
        .startUpload();
```

Answer (score 1):

use 
                .setMethod( "POST" )
                .setUtf8Charset()
                .setMaxRetries(2)
                .startUpload();